Alteryx Output Error with Microsoft Azure SQL Database
I'm trying to write a table on Microsoft Azure SQL Database with Alteryx version 2020.2.2.27029.
The table "D365.Prova" already exists in the db and the user I'm using has the following permissions on the db: db_owner, db_datawriter and db_datareader. I'm using the ODBC connection with "Overwrite Table (Drop)" option, but I'm getting the following error:

Output Data (42)
Error creating table "D365.Prova": [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction.
CREATE  TABLE "D365"."Prova" ("COL1" int,"COL2" varchar(10),"COL3" varchar(20),"COL4" varchar(20),"COL5" float,"COL6" varchar(50))"

If I use the "Append existing" option, no error is returned. If I use this option with the Pre Create SQL statement "TRUNCATE TABLE D365.Prova" I get the same above error. It seems that TRUNCATE and DROP give problems, while INSERT statement no.
Do you have any hint to solve the problem? I searched around but couldn't find any solution. Please tell me if you need any other info.

CREATE TABLE is allowed inside a transaction though... Are you sure it's that statement that's causing the error? Or are you actually using Azure Synapse? (That isn't Azure SQL Database; Azure SQL Synapse is a very different product.)

I can't replicate your problem: db<>fiddle Azure SQL Database

You are right, my fault, I'm actually using an Azure SQL Synapse

DDL statements cannot be wrapped in a transaction in Azure Synapse as noted in the limitations.

Thank you for the hint, with the DELETE FROM it works just fine!


Output Data (42) Error creating table "D365.Prova": [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction. CREATE TABLE"D365"."Prova" ("COL1" int,"COL2" varchar(10),"COL3" varchar(20),"COL4" varchar(20),"COL5" float,"COL6" varchar(50))"

The above error message states that

The use of DDL statements like CREATE TABLE is not allowed within a user-defined transaction in Azure Synapse dedicated pool.

Here are few Limitations suggested by @Thom A
As you have mentioned that you want to use DROP command.
I have tried the below approach as workaround:

You can use the Syntax for Azure synapse dedicated pool
DROP TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   
[;] 

OR
if  object_id ('ddpool.D365.Prova','U') is  not  null  drop  table ddpool.D365.Prova ;

OR
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ddpool].[Prova]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [ddpool].[Prova]


panda can you please check if the above solution helped you?

@panda can you please check if the above solution helped you?

Yes, it works! Thank you very much!
